# Upload big file not working

Tags: php, video, upload

As the title say I have a problem with uploading video.
I need to make a form that upload a file into a folder, it work with photos, and even with videos (or anyway, .mp4 file).
The problem comes when I try to upload big files, because PhP just fail.
I already modified php.ini post max size, max filesize, memory limit and even the time to process script or to input it, but if won't work anyway.
A strange things that I have notice is that when I try to upload big files, looks like php miss name and extension of the file, even if it works perfectly with small files.
How can I fix this? Is there any PhP command to set on the script, or something else in php.ini, looks like the php guide won't help me.Thank's

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES[image]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$target = "uploaded/";
$target = $target . $title.'.'.$extension; 
$pic=($_FILES['image']['name']); 
//Writes the photo to the server 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
} else {}
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing in your logs when the big files are uploaded but don't upload properly?

Comment: I can't see any error, I just have a function that should print the name of the file and the extension, usually it works, but if I upload big files looks like the variable of name and extension are empty

Comment: Wherever your errors are logged (Apache error log? Or somewhere else depending on how you're calling this), there should be some sort of error indicating why the file didn't upload correctly. Also, the `$_FILES` array contains an error code.. do you see anything there? Lastly, you mentioned that you edited php.ini. Did you specifically update `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to values higher than the file you're uploading? And did you restart your web server after making these changes? Perhaps run `phpinfo()` to view the settings and make sure they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: @NickCoons to be honest I didn't restart the web server, didn't know that's necessary to change PhP.ini.
I'll try and check if it will work.

Comment: @NickCoons thank's a lot, you solved my problem.
Yes I am stupid and didn't think to restart the server.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion in the comments, it appears that you missed restarting the web server after making your php.ini changes.  This file is read in at the start of the web server process, not each time a page is accessed.  So any changes to this file require a web server restart before they'll take affect.

To be clear, restarting the web server refers to the web server service, not the OS on the server.

Comment: "Already" as in after I posted my comment and you said that I solved your problem? :-)